# Is there a function which apply a displacement map / matrix on an image?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, polygon

I generate a displacement map / matrix of size (H, W, 2), each channel corresponding to the displacements of values in x and in y. The goal is to "move" the pixels values of a given image of shape (H, W, 3), with the values of the displacement map.

A simple example with only one channel (x for example) would be :

```
disp_map = np.array([[ 0, 1, 1, 0 ], 
                      [0, 0, 0, 0],
                      [1, 1, 0, 0]])

im = np.array([[ 0, 1, 1, 0 ], 
              [0, 1, 1, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]])

output = apply_disp_function(im, disp_map) 
output 
np.array([[ 1, 1, 0, 0 ], 
          [0, 1, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

I don't know if there are already a function which does it or I have to write a function in numpy with slicing.

Comment: Is `disp_map` map always integer, or do you need to care about sub-pixel displacements? And what should be done with "overflowing" displacements, ignore, wrap, ...?

Comment: @jdehesa Yes I think the `disp_map`should always be integer. What do you mean by sub-pixel displacements ? For overflowing displacements, they should probably be ignored. The `disp_map` is going to be applied to a binary image of polygons, which are going to be the mask of segmentation of a map (geographic map).

Comment: By sub-pixel I meant floating point displacement values, so for example if you displace 0.3 along the horizontal axis then 70% of the pixel value would remain in its place and 30% would go to the next one.

Comment: @jdehesa After some thoughts, no I don't care about it. If I correctly understand what you mean, with your example it would mean that for just two pixels : `np.array([[ 0, 1 ]])`, it would become `np.array([[ 0.3, 0.7 ]])`. And I still want a binary output.

Comment: in openCV, remap can be used for displacement. E.g. ins lens distortion correction it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution. Here the `disp_map` array is supposed to have one map for each axis in its last dimension. Displacements beyond the boundaries of the image would wrap around.

```
import numpy as np

def displace(im, disp_map):
    im = np.asarray(im)
    disp_map = np.asarray(disp_map)
    grid = np.ogrid[list(map(slice, disp_map.shape[:-1]))]
    result = np.zeros_like(im)
    np.add.at(result, tuple((g + disp_map[..., i]) % im.shape[i]
                            for i, g in enumerate(grid)), im)
    return result

# Each pair of values represents the number of rows and columns
# that each element will be displaced
disp_map = np.array([[[ 0,  0], [ 0, -1], [ 0,  1], [ 0,  0]],
                     [[ 0,  0], [ 1,  0], [ 1,  1], [ 0,  0]],
                     [[ 0,  1], [ 0,  1], [ 0,  0], [ 0,  0]]])
im = np.array([[ 0,  1,  1,  0],
               [ 0,  1,  1,  0],
               [ 0,  0,  0,  0]])
output = displace(im, disp_map)
print(output)
# [[1 0 0 1]
#  [0 0 0 0]
#  [0 1 0 1]]
```